# NodeJS - session data not stored after react-build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session

I've set a simple NodeJS web-app,
the basic functionally is to login, and then based on session data the app pull some data from the MySql.
that is working ([Link](https://github.com/Yanipo5/MenuCreator.git)).

once I write the client-side in react the session data is not stored (therefore app not working)
any ideas?
are there any specific react requirements for react to enable sessions?

note: in react after the page redirects (successfully) to menu.html
I'm expecting the req.session to have an auth property (=true)
but when I log the session data it is empty.
therefore I assume the session data is not stored.

*Login.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const con = require('../config/mysqlCon.js');
const session = require('express-session');
const router = express.Router();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))

router.post('/',approveUserPassword, function(req, res){

  if(req.session.auth){
    let url = '/menu.html';
    res.redirect(url);

  }else{
    req.session.auth = false;
    let url = '/index.html';
    res.redirect(url);

  }
});


function approveUserPassword(req, res, next) {

  let email = req.body.email;
  let psw = req.body.psw;
  let query = "SELECT id FROM Users " +
              "WHERE email= '" + email + "' AND " +
              "password='" + psw + "'";

  con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(result.length > 0){
      req.session.auth = true;
      req.session.rest_id = result[0].id;
      req.session.save();

    }else{
      req.session.auth = false;
    }

    next();
  });
}
```

just noted that 2 sessions are created, not sure why.
Node js listen on port 8080...

#### login

Time:1509727252952 
id:j1KIe081XzRhWKKKM7z5Jjv1N6Cderee
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }

#### menu

Time:1509727252955 
id:j1KIe081XzRhWKKKM7z5Jjv1N6Cderee
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  auth: true,
  rest_id: 100 }

#### login

Time:1509727253124 
id:rqCBY1fnH5WpS9M6Brp6RZokxMWzf0Pk 
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }

#### menu

Time:1509727253124 
id:rqCBY1fnH5WpS9M6Brp6RZokxMWzf0Pk 
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
rqCBY1fnH5WpS9M6Brp6RZokxMWzf0Pk

Comment: Just noted that there are 2 sessions created, still not sure why:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Express router create a new session not wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128749/express-router-create-a-new-session-not-wanted)

I guess it is some issue when creating the ajax request:

```
fetch('/api/myroute', {
    credentials: 'same-origin' // This is the line you are missing 
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    dispatch({
        type: types.MY_ACTION, forms: json, receivedAt: Date.now()
    })
})
```